# I need to remove the attribute tags <types> </types> without any value in an xml file using ant script

Tags: regex, xml, parsing, ant, xml-parsing

I need to remove the attribute tags   without any value in an xml file using ant script

Below is the XML I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>DoNothingTest</members>            
            <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
    </types>
    <types>
    </types>
    <types>
    </types>
    <types>
    </types>
<version>42.0</version>
</Package>
```

All the  tags that does not have a nesting tag or value should be removed from this xml . The output should look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>DoNothingTest</members>            
            <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>42.0</version>
</Package>
```

How can I achieve this using ANT script?

I am using the below ant script to perform the job, however, it trims only one occurence of 'types' tag.

```
<!--Format the generated XML file -->   
<target name="formatXML" depends="generatePackage.xml">
<property name="final-xml.file" value="temp/src/package.xml"/>

<for param="src-xml.absolute-path" list="${final-xml.file}">
        <fileset dir="temp/src/" includes="*.xml"/>
        <sequential>         

<replaceregexp file="${final-xml.file}"
    flags="s"
    match="\s*(?:&lt;\/([a-z]+)>)(\s*&lt;\1>)"
    replace=""/>
        </sequential>
    </for>  
</target>
```

How to iterate over the xml file and replace all occurences of 'types' tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke an XSLT transformation from Ant using the XSLT ant task. A stylesheet to remove empty `<types>` elements in namespace `http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata` consists of a boilerplate identity rule to copy all elements unchanged, plus the rule

```
<xsl:template match="x:types[not(*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]"
     xmlns:x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sadly, I am new to XML  and XSLT. Need more help in the syntax and how to include the XML and XSL together.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to write you a personal tutorial, and I'm not going to write the code for you: all I'm prepared to do is point you in the right direction. There's plenty of material that exists for learning XML and XSLT and you're going to have to climb that learning curve on your own; there's no short cut.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help Michael. I have got the solution..learned the hard way :)

Comment: Please find the xsl style I have used which will remove empty nodes in the xml:<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" >
<xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
    "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) 
     and normalize-space()=''
      ]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>